# How to proceed? Installing VMWareTools

Tags: vmware

I'm a new user setting up ubuntu on a virtual pc using VMWare Workstation. At this stage I want to install VMWare Tools. I have taken a few steps, however i do not know how to procceed [see image].

Steps I have taken so far.

1. Installing Ubuntu 14.04
2. unpacking the tar.gz file containing the vmware tools to desktopm
3. typing the three commands

   ```
   cd Desktop  
   cd vmware-tools-distrib  
   sudo ./vmware-install.pl [en-dash]d
   ```

I get asked to give sudo password.
next on my screen is this message

```
VMWare Tools 10.1.6 build-5214329 for Linux installer
Usage: ./vmware-install.pl
[[-][-]d[efault]]
default: Automatically answer questions with the proposed answer.
[[-][-]f[orce-install]]
force-install: install even if open-vm-tools packages are available for this
distribution.
[[-][-]prefix=<path to install product: bin, lib, doc>]
Put the installation at <path> instead of the default location.
This implies '--default'.
[[-][-]r[egenerate-cert]]
Force to regenerate server key/cert files if they already exist.
--clober -kernel-modules=<module1,module2,...
Forcefully removes any VMware related modules installed by any other installer 
and installs the modules provided by this installer. 
This is a comma separated list of modules.
```

Now what to do next?

Answer (score 7):

Don't install the distributed VMware Tools. VMware recommends that users install `open-vm-tools` (on Ubuntu Server) or `open-vm-tools-desktop` (on Ubuntu Desktop). See VMware KB article "[VMware support for Open VM Tools (2073803)](https://kb.vmware.com/kb/2073803)". Using `open-vm-tools` has the advantage that the package will then be upgraded together with all other packages on the system.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop
```

You may want to avoid installing useless recommended packages:

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install open-vm-tools-desktop
```